# Data Binding with parameter Angular 5

Tags: angular

I would like to separate some data. The situation is the next. A GET a JSON from my database and it has some different columns. For example: id, name, message, type. I would like to bind the data into different divs depending on the type content.

> So I want to bind just those data's which contains the required
>   strings ( like = 'connection error')

In my html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data ">{{data.type}}</div>
```

I want to show all the data from the JSON but on separated way. There are any way to give a requirement for the binding content ? Like this {{ data.type=''}} The requirement will be the type columns content. 
I try it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data; let type = connection error">
      {{data.message}} {{data.id}}
</div>

<div *ngFor="let data of data.data; let type = request error">
      {{data.message}} {{data.id}}
</div>
```

**My TS is:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorsService } from './errors.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-errors',
  templateUrl: './errors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./errors.component.css'],   
})
export class ErrorsComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any = [];

    constructor(private errorsService: ErrorsService) {   }

    ngOnInit() {      
        this.errorsService.getAllErrors().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data
        });  
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly it is you want but if you just want to do a simple check for the `type` you can do that with `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch`.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data;>
  <div *ngIf="data.type === 'connection-error'">
    There was a connection error
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="data.type === 'request-error'">
    There was a request error
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. If you want to solve it in the template you can create a custom pipe that filters entries with a certain type. Result would look something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data.data | type : 'connection error">
    {{data.message}} {{data.id}}
</div>
```

Here are the docs on how to setup a custom pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

The second approach is TS-based. You can split them up in your TypeScript into 4 separate variables. This can be easily achieved with a Map.reduce() (or Map.forEach/filter&map as well)